# Maven and Java_Home

Tags: java, apache, maven, environment-variables, java-home

I am using Netbeans 7.4.
I down loaded the Maven3.1 and extracted in  C:\Apache\apache-maven-3.1.1.
System Variables are set as :

> JAVA_HOME is set at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45 M2_HOME is set
>   to C:\Apache\apache-maven-3.1.1
>
> Path is set to  C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Windows
>   Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin

Now when from the command line I command ..>mvn -v I get this this error:

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory. JAVA_HOME =
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45;" Please set the JAVA_HOME variable
>   in your environment to match the location of your Java installation

Comment: what is the output of `echo %JAVA_HOME%`? how did you set JAVA_HOME? It has a semicolon at the end that shouldn't be there.

Comment: JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45;" - you have ";" at the end - that seems to be wrong

Comment: Its resolved by setting on Netbean->Tools->Options->Java-> and setting MavenHome.

Comment: @Nizet      Output of echo %JAVA_HOME% is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you need to create

---

```
system variable like this:
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45
CLASS_PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\lib
```

---

```
User variable
ME = C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin
M2_HOME = C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.1.1
MAVEN_OPTS = -Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

---

```
Path - insert into your path
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin
```

---

Don't forget to reboot system

Comment: @javaz, create your environment as I told you and you got it. I could it and don't bother with lazy guys who are just downgrading votes.

Answer (score 3):

Read the error message carefully.  It says:

```
... JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45;" ...
```

See the stray semicolon?  Get rid of it!

The JAVA_HOME variable should contain a directory name ... not a "search path".  What you are telling Maven to do is to use a directory whose name contains a semicolon.  That directory doesn't exist.

---

Meta-advice: it pays to read error messages carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar situation. I resolved it by removing the semicolon(;) at the end of `JAVA_HOME`.

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11
```

Instead of

```
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Java\jdk* is the installation directory of the development kit. Find a "jre" folder inside Program Files\Java. That "JRE" folder should be your JAVA_HOME

Comment: jdk is superset of jre, maven requires jdk

Answer (score 0):

The value `JAVA_HOME` should **not** contain quotes, because several Maven plugins will append something like 'bin\javac.exe', which would give an invalid path if the quotes are still there.